# Seeking publicly available ArcIMS server?

Tags: arcims, service-recommendations

Does anyone know of a publicly / externally available ESRI ArcIMS server / service / services with the full US base map?

Doesn't have to be free, but that's always good.  I've seen some city-specific ones, but I need a USA one with street-level detail.

Comment: I doubt there are any that cover the whole US. As you have seen, there are some made available by universities and some local governments. The only one that came to mind is www.geographynetwork.com, however I am not sure if it still works. I was able to connect to it from ArcGIS Desktop 10.2, but am unable to preview any service.

Comment: Yeah, geographynetwork was retired long ago. I'm with Alex on this one. The only ones I've seen still active are smaller municipalities. I haven't seen any nation wide servers in a few years now. Goodluck in your search.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov and KHibma thanks for your quick replies.  I'll keep my fingers crossed in case anyone knows.